# Does Reinhardt's shield block all abilities?

Tags: overwatch

Reinhardt's main strength is his shielding abilities and the protection he provides for his team, but Are there any abilities that cannot be blocked by Reinhardt's barrier field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Composed with assistance from this [Source](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/reinhardt.html#barrier):

> The Barrier does NOT block the following:
>
> - Melee attacks.  Reinhardt and his shield will both take full damage from a single melee attack.
> - Sombra's EMP will destroy his shield, and hack everything that was behind it.
> - Orisa's halt ability will pass through it, however it will not suck his allies from behind a barrier if it detonates on the other side.
> - Some channeled weapons, including:  Winston's Tesla Cannon, but Symmetra's Photon Projector beam will be blocked.
> - Reinhardt's Fire Strike and Symmetra's Photon Orbs.
> - Hanzo's Dragonstrike
> - Junkrat's Rip Tire
>
> Fire Strike and Photon Orbs can actually pass through and damage
>   everything in its path, including Reinhardt, his barrier and anyone
>   else behind Reinhardt.

Do also note that Reinhardt's shield does not block ally projectiles.  This means you should combo with a Bastion or any other front line assault that will make best use of your shield.

Comment: The following video shows Hanzo's ultimate killing Reinhardt while the latter is using his shield. https://youtu.be/oOVb9x0zd6M?t=1m12s

Comment: Note that Reinhardt's barrier doesn't keep Junkrat's Riptire from passing, but it will absorb the damage from the explosion.

Comment: Also note that the shield will block an Earthshatter only if the shield is touching the ground. Similarly, it will block McCree's flashbangs if they are thrown into the shield, but not if they are thrown _over_ the shield, which may stun the Reinhardt.

Comment: Similar to the Riptire, Junkrat's Concussion Mine is also quite effective against Reinhardt: you can toss it at Reinhardt's feet, wait until he steps over it and then set it off. Not only will it deal damage, it will also send Reinhardt flying, exposing anyone hiding behind his shield.

Comment: Mei's Blizzard is also not blocked in any way.

Comment: Another note: Most "basic" projectiles (any regular gunfire) are simply absorbed by the shield, but some persist after hitting it. Junkrat's mine and Widowmaker's spider will both stop and bounce off the shieldif they hit it. Hanzo's sonar arrow will actually stick in the shield for as long as it's up, and then drop to the floor as soon as the shield disappears. (I've actually seens a Hanzo get a kill by shooting the sonar arrow at the shield of a very low health Rein - as soon as Rein dropped the shield, he walked into the now-falling arrow and was "hit" by the projectile and died.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some of the new champions:

- All of Doomfist's abilities will go through the shield other than the shockwave from his E. This is because they all count as "melee" skills. Doomfist's primary fire is still blocked, as usual.
- Moira's healing beam (primary fire) will still heal allies behind an enemy shield. Her damage beam (secondary fire) stops at the shield however.
- Moira's orb will travel through enemy shields. If you use the damaging orb, it will not deal any damage to enemies until it has passed the shield.