# Does Earthshatter go through shields?

Tags: overwatch

[Earthshatter](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Reinhardt#Abilities) is [Reinhardt](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Reinhardt)'s [ultimate ability](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ultimate_ability). Does it pass through an enemy Reinhardt's Barrier Field (shield), particularly? Winston's Barrier? Zarya's Particle Barrier?

Comment: Almost duplicate: [Does Reinhardt's shield block all abilities?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/264451/108003)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Earthshatter will not pass through shields. I have [tried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqK1C5L4s7A&index=9&list=PLawWp2iOZJgfHO8o8TLltlQ54ZEQdV6y1) this, only to be disappointed.

Do note that Reinhardt's shield has to be touching the ground to block Earthshatter. If the Reinhardt is looking up, it will not block Earthshatter. (props to @Studoku for this).

Comment: Reinhardt's shield only works if it's touching the ground. If he's looking up, it can go under the shield.

Comment: @Studoku I had not noticed that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about touching the ground and always wondered why it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't

Comment: What about defence matrix?

Comment: @Studoku "The shield does NOT have to touch the ground in order to block Reinhardt's Ultimate Ability "Earthshatter"." - https://www.reddit.com/r/Competitiveoverwatch/comments/4yp0l1/reinhardt_shield_inconsitencies/